# Как можно прицепить обработчик события ко всем элементам, у которых установлен определенный Css-класс?

Tags: css3, javascript, css, pure_js

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно поставить обработчик события (допустим, `onclick`) ко всем элементам, которым задан определенный `css-`класс.
Иначе говоря, допустим, есть `css-`класс `myClass`, на страничке есть элемент

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myClass"/>
```

Как ко всем элементам с классом `myClass` установить обработчик `onclick`? 
Внимание! Без использования библиотек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое решение, более-менее кроссбраузерное...**UPD** with @Ilya_Pirogov

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
document.getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
    // реализация функции
function x_getElementsByClassName(className){
    var testClass = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)");
    var elements = document.all;
    var returnElements = [];
    var current;
    var length = elements.length;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        current = elements[i];
        if(testClass.test(current.className)){
            returnElements.push(current);
        }
    }
    return returnElements;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Работает прекрасно!!! Спасибо!

Comment: Firefox не справляется :(.   
Ругается на `document.all`, говорит, что `elements` undefined.!!!

Comment: вот:

    var all = document.all || document.getElementsByTagName('*');

ненавижу лису, уж простите.

Comment: Да. Но с точки зрения меня как пользователя, она удобна. Спасибо за дополнение.

Comment: Если уж говорить о кроссбраузерности, то, вероятно, лучше сделать так:

if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
        // реализация функции
    }
}

Comment: М, да, вы правы. А насчет регулярки, я бы был более осторожен: как `\b` реагирует на `_` ? =)

Answer (score 3):

```
Elements = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for(var i=0; i<Elements.length; i++) {
    Elements[i].onclick = eventFunction;
}
```

Comment: неа, не сработает в чуть более старых браузерах. =) В новых - да.

Comment: ИМХО писать под браузеры 10+ летней давности ЭТО БРЕД<br>
Браузеры которые не ie и которые моложе 10 лет это по вашему новые?О_о

Comment: И это сработало!

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так, но работать будет не очень быстро :)

```
for (i in document.all) { 
    el = document.all[i]; 
    if (el.className.indexOf('fl') != -1) { 
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('Hello!');
        }, false); 
    }
}
```

Хотя лучше, конечно, через регулярку проверять.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
    if(divs[i].cssClass="myClass")
    divs[i].onclick= function(){

    }
}
```

можно еще посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-onmouseout)

Comment: divs[i].cssClass="myClass" - двойное равенство надо =) Плюс, если элемент имеет два класса, решение не сработает